# Does anyone know all parameters of get_comments()

Tags: php, comments, comment-form, parameter

Here is [the link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments). There is a lot of parameters that didn't explain yet, and I want to know all about it. Thought, I have try to read the code, but can not understand it at all. The more I try to read code, the more queries I have.

Does anyone know about those parameters? Especially 'parent', 'post_parent', 'fields', 'include_unapproved', 'comment__in', 'post__in'.

Plz help me, and I really appreciated. Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- parent : Comments can be replies to other comments. Every comment has an ID number. When the comment is a reply, then it will have a "parent" which is the ID of the comment it is replying to. Putting a comment ID in here will get all the replies to that comment.
- post_parent : Posts can be children of other posts as well. This is how things like hierarchical pages work. Putting an ID in here will get all the comments that are made to all the child posts of that ID.
- fields : Determines what comment fields you want to get back. If you only want the Comment IDs, for example, you would put "ids" here.
- include_unapproved : Whether to include unapproved comments or not. True/false.
- comment__in : An array of comment IDs that you want to get.
- post__in : An array of post IDs that you want to get the comments of.